# Why is conversion time 10 times slower in my ESP32-WROOM-32U?

Tags: esp32

The following code is used to show conversion time and maximum sampling frequency. The code is from [this GitHub page](https://github.com/s-marley/ESP32_FFT_VU) for a spectrum analyzer based on the ESP32. The author in his YouTube video shows that his reading is around 10 μs for the conversion time and around 100000 Hz as maximum sampling frequency.

Here is my case:

```
Conversion time: 93.54 uS
Max sampling frequency: 10690.92 Hz
```

It is 10 times slower! What is the problem?

```cpp
#define AUDIO_IN_PIN 35

int analogValue;
unsigned long newTime;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("START");
}

void loop() {
  newTime = micros();
  
  // Do 1 million reads and record time taken
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    analogValue = analogRead(AUDIO_IN_PIN);
    
  }

  float conversionTime = (micros() - newTime) / 1000000.0;
  Serial.println("END");
  Serial.print("Conversion time: ");
  Serial.print(conversionTime);
  Serial.println(" uS");

  Serial.print("Max sampling frequency: ");
  Serial.print((1.0 / conversionTime) * 1000000);
  Serial.println(" Hz");
}
```

Edit: Sorry my bad, I added `yield()` to see what happens, but nothing has changed.

Edit: I have tried the @thebusybee recommandation and the result is the same!

```cpp
void loop() {
  
  newTime = micros();
  //delay(10);
  //delay(100);
  delay(1000);
  // Do 1 million reads and record time taken
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    analogValue = analogRead(AUDIO_IN_PIN);
    
  }

  float conversionTime = (micros() - newTime) / 1000000.0;
   Serial.println("END");
  Serial.print("Conversion time: ");
  Serial.print(conversionTime);
  Serial.println(" uS");

  Serial.print("Max sampling frequency: ");
  Serial.print((1.0 / conversionTime) * 1000000);
  Serial.println(" Hz");
}
```

No luck yet! But I have found a better solution for my case [esp32_is2_adc_reading](https://github.com/silderan/esp32_is2_adc_reading)

Comment: Probably that yield() as it might introduce task switching and so

Comment: In the github project, that you linked, the author doesn't yield

Comment: Yeah, I added yield() to see what happens, but nothing has changed!

Comment: Try removing the `println("START");` from setup(). Serial interrupts while transmitting data during the sampling stage might slow it down.

Comment: I added the start and end print to calculate the time, it wasn't there in the beginning, yet nothing changes.

Comment: Delay before the loop reading the analog values, to make sure that no serial transmission takes place. You have some 60 to 70 characters per test, these need about 6ms at 115200 baud. Start with `delay(10);` to see what happens. -- Please [edit] your question to **add** your then current code and results.

Comment: @the busybee no luck mate!

Comment: Next try: Toggle a port pin in the acquiring loop and use the oscilloscope to see what's really happening.

Comment: Read this: [Slower ADC Sampling rate using firmware versions 2.0.6, 1.0.6, or 1.0.5 compared to version 1.0.4](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/7689). Earlier versions of the ESP32 Arduino Core might have had a much shorter ADC conversion time.

Comment: Also see here on Electronics StackExchange: [Why doesn't the sampling rate of the ESP32 go any higher than 10 kHz?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/647605/why-doesnt-the-sampling-rate-of-the-esp32-go-any-higher-than-10-khz). No solutions however.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please write an actual answer that is self-contained and mark it. This is the way this site is intended to work. You can and probably should provide the link to the external resource. However, the answer shall have enough details to understand it without visiting that resource.